# Select join and PHP

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables:

```
T1
id | id_book | barcode |classroom_id

T2
id | book_title | barcode | etc..
```

I want to select all the data about books used in a specific classroom.

I am trying with this code, but with 0 results:

```
SELECT * FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 
ON T1.barcode = T2.barcode 
WHERE T1.classroom_id = '$ids'
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Presumably, you have no `classroom_id` that matches `'$ids'`.  Also, you should learn to pass parameters in using parameters, not by munging query strings.

Comment: debug query and check what you are getting there